# Passing files to automatically trigered build from another build

Tags: jenkins

So I am in the situation of needing my master job to be able to pass files to my job triggered by the master job.
The job is triggered **during the master job**, I can't use artifact.

Anyone has ever did that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the files are present in master's workspace.
Then one (messy) way will be to make second job a parametrized job and pass the master job workspace to it as a parameter.
Then in the second job use the master workspace location in a windows batch file to copy stuff from there to the place where you want. Run the batch file as the first build step for the second job.
Then business as usual.

Comment: Would not have been a bad idea but we cannot assume that we will be on the same build machine.

Comment: I went with my plan B which is that i'll cut the first job where I need to call the second job and do the rest of the first job in the second one.

Comment: If you use something like xcopy(on windows) then actually it works well between master and slaves(running on different physical box).

Comment: Could u elaborate a little bit more, since my plan B isnt valide anymore. xcopy would be a valide option

Comment: Build A needs to fail if Build B fails.

Comment: Before thinking of using xcopy, do a commandline xcopy between the slave and master to make sure that the login you use has the permissions to do file transfers between computers. You can run xcopy command under run windows batch file as a build step.
Regarding Build A failing if Build B fails.
There might be plugins out there. One way:
1. Start main job.
2. Make main job launch the second job.
3. Once second job finishes then run groovy script to check for results. Fail the build if error.
http://blog.dahanne.net/2014/04/02/using-jenkins-hudson-remote-api-to-check-jobs-status/